# Single Page Backbone App Notification when code version changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, single-page-application

I have a single page backbone app that is served by a stack using ruby on rails.  My issue is that if there is a code change in production, the users will not receive the new code until they refresh.  I would like to provide a way of letting the user know when they need to refresh.  Can any of you provide suggestions, or methods you tried in the past?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [webSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) requests for this purposes.